# Programatically check if google protocol buffer field is required

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

Is it possible to programmatically check if a given proto field is marked as `required` vs `optional`? I'm using python and have a `FieldDescriptor` object, but can't find a way to determine whether the field is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.descriptor.FieldDescriptor-class) indicates that your `FieldDescriptor` should have a `label` attribute indicating whether it's optional, required, or repeated.

```
from google.protobuf.descriptor import FieldDescriptor

if fd.label == FieldDescriptor.LABEL_OPTIONAL:
    # do thing
elif fd.label == FieldDescriptor.LABEL_REQUIRED:
    # do other thing
else:
    # do third thing
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I think my answer could help someone.

I have made a recursive function that checks if the given message in a JSON format has all required fields of a given proto message. It also checks for a required fields of nested messages.

As you can see, `label` attribute is used to check if the field is required (this is already covered in accepted answer).

```
def checkRequiredFields(protoMsg, jsonMsg, missingFields=[]):
    from google.protobuf.descriptor_pb2 import FieldDescriptorProto as fdp

    if hasattr(protoMsg, 'DESCRIPTOR'):
        for field in protoMsg.DESCRIPTOR.fields:
            if fdp.LABEL_REQUIRED == field.label:
                if field.name in jsonMsg:
                    newProtoMsg = getattr(protoMsg, field.name)
                    newJsonMsg = jsonMsg[field.name]
                    missingFields = __checkRequiredFields(newProtoMsg,
                                                          newJsonMsg,
                                                          missingFields)
                else:
                    missingFields.append(field.name)

    return missingFields
```

Function can be used like this:

```
protoMsg = MyProtoMessage() # class generated from the proto files
jsonMsg = json.loads(rawJson) # message in a JSON format
missingFields = checkRequiredFields(protoMsg, jsonMsg)
```

Comment: There's a mutable default argument bug here - the default value of `missingFields` is created once, at function definition time, instead of on each call that needs it.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica isn't that the point in this function, that list is empty only on the first call, but not empty on every other call?

Comment: No. That's handled by passing a non-default value in the recursive call. The mutable default argument bug means that if you call the function again later, on a completely unrelated message, `missingFields` will still be full of stuff from last time.